# How to disable a specific email in ActionMailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I would like to disable only certain emails. 
I have a mailer class that has a method which is used to send the emails. I cannot get rid of the method itself as it is called from several places. I would like to change the method in such a way that the calls to the method doesn't actually send any email.

Answer (score 0):

You could throw this in your method or use it where you call deliver on the email that you do not want to send in production

```
 unless Rails.env.production?
```

EDIT

If you just want to check the class of the call

```
 if self.is_a?(class)
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear earlier, I want to disable only certain emails. It is not environment specific.
And I do not want to get rid of all deliver method calls, I will prefer to do it at a single location.

Comment: Still not clear.. These emails are all using the same method in actionmailer and you only want select emails to actually deliver?

Comment: So lets say I have two mailer classes with each of them having 1 method which is called after deliver. I only want one of the classes to be disabled and not send any emails. Irrespective of the fact from where the call is made inside the application to deliver.

Comment: Not really, with this edit, I would have had to add this conditional everywhere I had 'deliver' call. Instead, I ended up adding a different conditional in the worker that executes all queued up tasks. Thanks for the help though.